# Difference Between stdout=subprocess.PIPE and stdout=PIPE

Tags: python, pipe, subprocess

So The title pretty much explains my question. What is the difference between stdout=subprocess.PIPE and stdout=PIPE? Both come from the subprocess module, but why would you use one over the other? How do you use stdout=PIPE? I.e. capture the output? Or print it to the screen? I only know how to redirect it with subprocess.PIPE.

e.g.

```
import subprocess
from subprocess import PIPE
p = subprocess.Popen(['samtools', 'view', 'bamfile.bam'], stdout=PIPE)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
from subprocess import PIPE
```

makes `subprocess.PIPE` available under the alternative name `PIPE`; it is equivalent to:

```
PIPE = subprocess.PIPE
```

Therefore, it does not matter which version you choose. `subprocess.PIPE` makes it clear where the variable is coming from, but is slightly longer.